# Python cannot import specific PyQt4 QtWebKit modules

Tags: python, pyqt4, centos6, qtwebkit

I'm having an odd module import issue when trying to work with PyQt4. I'm able to run the following imports, independent of each other, without getting errors:

```
import PyQt4
from PyQt4 import *
from PyQt4 import QtWebKit
from PyQt4.QtWebkit import *
```

I start getting errors when I try to import specific modules in PyQt4.QtWebKit though, but it doesn't happen to all of the modules. Here's an example:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/webscraping/webkit.py", line 16, in <module>
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebFrame, QWebView, QWebElement, QWebPage, QWebSettings
ImportError: cannot import name QWebElement
```

Every module in that error works except QWebElement. Notice that the error says that it can't import the module, not that the module doesn't exist. I've tried reinstalling the packages but haven't had much luck.

Here are my system specs and packages I installed:

- CentOS Linux 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Python 2.6.6

Installed:

- sip.x86_64 (Version : 4.9.3, Release : 1.el6)
- qt.x86_64 (Version : 4.6.2, Release : 28.el6_5)
- PyQt4.x86_64 (Version : 4.6.2, Release : 9.el6)
- PyQt4-devel.x86_64 (Version : 4.6.2, Release : 9.el6)
- PyQt4-webkit.x86_64 (Version : 4.6.2, Release : 8.el6)
- PyQt4-webkit-devel.x86_64 (Version : 4.6.2, Release : 8.el6)
- webscraping (Version: 1.4)

Comment: Which version of PyQt are you using? It seems that QWebElement was introduced in version 4.6

Comment: All of the most important information is missing from your specs: Qt version, PyQt version, sip version. I would guess that `QWebElement` (note that it's _name_ of a class, not a module, hence the error message), is not present in the version of Qt you're using.

Comment: Sorry about that, in my rush to get this out I forgot to slap in qt and each package's versions. Should be updated correctly now.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for pointing that out. QWebElement, according to http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebelement.html it was added in 4.6 so it should be part of the package that I installed, but it looks like that isn't the case.

Comment: @Majordeek. Okay, but see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PyQt versions don't necessarily stay in sync with the Qt versions anymore. PyQt-4.7 is the first version that fully supports Qt-4.6.

I still have an old build of PyQt-4.7, and I can confirm that the import statement in the question does not produce errors.